# Python: How to order by dynamically to a RawQuery Set

Tags: python, sql, django

Below is the Query:

```
select a.*
from customers a INNER JOIN
     (SELECT city,M IN(id) as id
      FROM customers
      GROUP BY city
     ) b
     ON a.city = b.city AND a.id = b.id;
```

I have a list which are dynamic from time to time.
But for better understanding i am giving a sample.

```
order_field = ['check-in', 'check-out ASC',.....]
```

This order_field is set depending on User choose sort by option from UI.
Here I am mapping all the incoming field with my column name in DB.

```
Note: ASC for ascending. This could be like DESC also
```

Then how can I get the order by result which is dynamically fit the fields on order_field.

Anyone having any idea?

Answer (score 0):

try this one. I declare the order field at sql.

```
DECLARE @order_field varchar(15)
SET @order_field = 'DESC '

a.*
from customers a INNER JOIN
 (SELECT city,M IN(id) as id
  FROM customers
  GROUP BY city
 ) b
 ON a.city = b.city AND a.id = b.id;
 ORDER BY  CASE WHEN @order_field ='ASC' THEN a.city END,
           CASE WHEN @order_field ='DESC' THEN a.city END DESC
```